# Programmatically Determine if gpg-agent Will Ask for Passphrase

Tags: gnupg

I have `gpg-agent` running with a cached passphrase for an hour or so.  I encrypt my email account passwords for `offlineimap` IMAP sync utility and have the script pass in the passwords by decrypting them from a GPG-encrypted file.

Since I run `offlineimap` with systemd as it is a cron job, it will naturally pop-up a pinentry program and ask for the password.  I was wondering is there a way to programtically confirm if `gpg-agent` will need a passphrase so I can query for the information, and gracefully exit the systemd/cron job if interactive passphrase input is required.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: This seems relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71135/how-can-i-find-out-what-keys-gpg-agent-has-cached-like-how-ssh-add-l-shows-yo

Answer (score 6):

I just have the similar plan to periodically fetch/sync may emails using `mbsync` and `cron`.  The passwords are managed by [`pass`](http://passwordstore.org/) which uses GnuPG to encrypt the sensitive data.

The newer GnuPG (I'm using v2.1.18) must use `gpg-agent` to ask for the necessary passphrase to decrypt the private keys.
And `gpg-agent` will be automatically started when e.g., I invoke `pass` to get the password for my email account, and will pop up the *pinentry* dialog asking the passphrase.

I don't want to configure `gpg-agent` to cache my passphrase for too long (e.g., 1 day or even 1 year), and I don't want the annoying *pinentry* dialog from `gpg-agent` triggered by the cron jobs, which should be just quiet.

I think the `mbsync` cron job will sync my emails when `gpg` can just decrypt the password for `pass` without triggering `gpg-agent` to ask the user for the passphrase, otherwise, the cron job will just exit.

I found GnuPG has the `--pinentry-mode` option, which may have values:

- `default` : Use the default of the agent, which is `ask`.
- `ask` : Force the use of the Pinentry.
- `cancel` : Emulate use of Pinentry's cancel button.
- `error` : Return a Pinentry error (``No Pinentry'').
- `loopback` : Redirect Pinentry queries to the caller.  Note that in contrast to Pinentry the user is not prompted again if he enters a bad password.

Therefore, I can explicitly disable pinentry usage by passing `--pinentry-mode cancel` or `--pinentry-mode error`, and let `gpg` try to sign/decrypt a message.  If it succeeded, then `gpg-agent` already has the cached passphrase and will not pop up the *pinentry* dialog; otherwise, the sign/decrypt test just failed.

For example:

When `gpg-agent` doesn't cache the needed passphrase:

```
$ echo "test" | \
  gpg2 --sign --batch --no-tty --pinentry-mode error \
       --local-user <you@example.com> -o /dev/null

# Return code: 2
# OUTPUT:
# gpg: signing failed: No pinentry
# gpg: signing failed: No pinentry
```

When `gpg-agent` has already cached the passphrase, the same command will succeed and return status code 0.

If I use `--pinentry-mode cancel`, then `gpg` fails with `Operation cancelled`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I wonder if it is sensible to have such an option because it could easily misused like:

```
#!/bin/sh
if gpg_ready_to_work_without_pinentry; then
    do_something_malicious_with_the_key;
fi
```

and you'd not have any chance to detect a misuse. (In fact I even don't like that every program in my login session has access to my possibly unlocked key without a way to check if it's unlocked or not. I found your question on the search for an option to gpg-agent to pop up a confirmation dialog for each usage exactly for this reason.)